# PC takes a long time to print since joining domain

Tags: windows-xp, printing, printer, windows-domain

I have a computer that exhibits strange printing problems.

When I print from a domain account it usually takes a long time (30 sec to +1 min) for an application to send the job to the printer. During this time the application freezes/hangs. When we use a local admin account it works instantly. Strangely sometimes it also prints instantly from the domain logons.

The computer was in production in a workgroup environment for years (and worked just fine) until about 3 months ago when I joined it to the domain.

The print delay applies to any application such as MS Word, Excel, Adobe Reader, Notepad etc. Even the drivers' Print Test Page function.

Both accounts (local & domain) have Local Admin rights on the machine.

The computer runs windows XP and we have HP 4015 + Xerox 7545 printers. The printer and driver are locally installed. I do not have a print server. The DC runs Windows Server 2008 R2.

**What I have done so far**

- I re-installed the XEROX driver - did not make a difference
- I logged on with another domain account - same problem
- I checked the task manager while I was printing something and did not find a process that particularly sticks out.
- Ask another IT support tech
- disabled Anti-Virus
- (Windows Firewall was already off)

**Update**

- I disjoined and rejoined the PC from the Domain

**Update: 24 Apr 2015**

- I deleted all printers
- removed all drivers and ports (printers > File > Printer Server)
- I uninstalled Vipre Antivirus
- ran CCleaner
- Reinstalled Vipre
- Reinstalled the printers
- Stopped the Printer Spoooler Service, Delete files in C:\Windows\System32\Printers > restarted the service

I tried to print a test page from printer properties and it was still slow...

**Partial Success!**

Then I disabled a function in Vipre Active Protection that checks all files when they are moved and/or openend. I rebooted.

Now when we print it still takes some time to spool but the MS Office and Adobe does not freeze. So we have some improvements.

**Update 29 Apr 2015**

I have revisited the Event log and found some userserv #1053 and netlogon errors. It seemed that the computer was not able to get Group Policy updates from the Domain Controller (DC). It said the RPC Server was not running and sure enough the PRC service was not running. I started it which further improved the problem.

Another thing I fixed was that the computer got a wrong IP address when pining the DC. So I deleted the wrong entry in the DNS.

After that I ran the `gpupdate /force` and I did not get the userserv error again.

The problem is almost gone now. But we just had another random slow in printing from that computer. The next print was fine again.

---

Any suggestions or pointers to handle this would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I know the simplest handling would be to just get a modern computer which we will do soon.

Comment: It could be a networking problem, the workgroup and the domain, were they on the same network?

Comment: Do other computers on the domain with their own printer display the same problem?  Any domain-related, or printer-related errors in the Event Logs?  Have you tried disjoining and rejoining this one PC to the domain?

Comment: @SoyFilipo: Thank you. The workgroup and the domain are on the same network.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Thanks. no other computers on the domain or workgroup experience this problem. I have not tried to disjoin it and and rejoin it to the domain but no luck. One interesting thing was that I had trouble connecting the machine back. It said it could not find the domain. DNS server was set correctly. But the ping got the wrong ip address. I then modified the host file but it still did not work. After another reboot and reverting the host I was able to join it.  Any other Ideas?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I also checked the error logs and there was one that might be interesting: `Source: Userenv; Event ID: 1053: Description: Windows cannot determine the user or computer name (The RPC server is unavailable) Group policy processing aborted.`

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: on you suggestion I disjoined and rejoined the computer from the domain...but it did not make a difference. I will continue to search the internet for a solution but if you have another idea I would be much obliged.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I updated the questions. I am almost there with this "stubborn" computer.